# PHP/Ajax simple chat - set admin username color to red

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat

I have a simple PHP/Ajax chat app that allows users to talk to each other in a unified chat window.  I want a user with the role 'admin' to have their username show up as red in the chat window, regardless of who is logged in.

Here's the user table columns:
[image: user table columns]

And here's the message table columns:
[image: message table columns]

I have the username and role from the user table in a session - `$_SESSION['name']` and `$_SESSION['role']` - and the `$_SESSION['name']` writes to the `user` column in the messages table.

Here's the PHP switch statement I'm using to `get` and `send` the messages into the window:

```
switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
        case "sendMessage":
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO messages SET user = ?, message = ?");
            $run = $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['name'], $_REQUEST['message']]);

            if ( $run ) {
                echo 1;
                exit;
            }
        break;
        case "getMessages":
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages");
            $run = $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $chat = '';
            foreach($results as $message){
                $chat .= '<div class="single-message border">
                            <strong class="text-uppercase">'.$message->user.': </strong>
                            <p> '.$message->message.'</p>
                            <span class="float-right">'.date('h:i a', strtotime($message->date)).'</span>
                          </div>';
            }
            echo $chat;
        break;
```

For reference, here's the ajax:

```
LoadChat();

setInterval(function(){
    LoadChat();
}, 1000);

function LoadChat() {
    $.post('handlers/messages.php?action=getMessages', function(response){

        var scrollpos = $('#chat').scrollTop();
        var scrollpos = parseInt(scrollpos) + 520;
        var scrollHeight = $('#chat').prop('scrollHeight');

        $('#chat').html(response);
        if( scrollpos < scrollHeight ){

        } else {
            $('#chat').scrollTop( $('#chat').prop('scrollHeight') );
        }
    });
}

$('.textarea').keyup(function(e){
    if( e.which == 13 ) {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    var message = $('.textarea').val();
    $.post('handlers/messages.php?action=sendMessage&message='+message, function(response){
        if( response == 1) {
            LoadChat();
            document.getElementById("messageFrm").value = "";
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My thought is I need to match the user from the message table to the username from the user table, check for the role, then highlight the username in the chat window, but I don't know where to start. I going to keep trying using an inner join in the sql statement but I'm getting confused on how to phrase that.

This isn't correct (and where I'm getting confused) but is where I'm starting:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM message m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.username WHERE role = :role AND u.username = :username';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([ 'role' => "$_SESSION['role']", 'username' => $_SESSION['name']]);
```

Comment: I think after fetching data you can check if the `role="Admin"`  then you don't need to put this `role = :role` condition in your query .

Comment: Along with the messages, fetch user role as well from database like this - $sql = 'SELECT m.*, u.role FROM message m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.username WHERE u.role = :role AND u.username = :username';. I have assumed that you are storing user role in the table 'users'.  And then in your switch case statement -  case "getMessages": - you can check if the user role is admin,  make it red - may be using css..

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: @Strawberry - I posted pictures of the columns in a database - I've been asked to before - what's is the problem with that?

Comment: @Swati - good point - thanks for that.

Comment: @T.Shah - Thanks - I'll give that a go - looks like I was close with my attempt!

Comment: There's a FAQ for that somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to use fetchObject instead and iterate till it returns false.
this approach is less memory-intensive and quicker, because you makes one array instead off array and string.

It's ok to add "[admin]" in this way, but you have repeated code.
If you want to change something in the future in this code it will be pain.
E.g. when you want to change "single-message" class name you must do it in two places.
Second mistake is using fetchAll and iterationg throught fetched array.

This code should be better:

```
case "getMessages":

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT m.*, u.role FROM messages m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.username');
            $stmt->execute();

            $chat = '';
            while( $message = $stmt->fetchObject() ) {
                $admin = "";
                if ($message->role == 'Admin') {
                    $admin = "[admin]";
                }
                    $chat .= '<div class="single-message border">
                        <strong class="text-uppercase">' . $message->user . '</strong>'
                       . $admin . '<p> ' . $message->message . '</p>
                        <span class="float-right">' . date('h:i a', strtotime($message->date)) . '</span>
                      </div>';

            }
            echo $chat;
        break;
```

On the other side, you can do all this things better.
Think about rendering your GUI on the client side.
Instead returnig html code from getMessages, build array of messages object and send it as JSON.
This is better approach because in this case PHP is reponsible only for generating data, not layout.
When you want to change sth in layout, change it on client side.
Code will be cleaner and separated. Each part of your application will have own responsibility.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT m.*, u.role FROM messages m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.username');
$stmt->execute();

$messages = [];
while ($message = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $message->date_formatted = date('h:i a', strtotime($message->date));
    $messages[] = $message;
}
```

i think you will know how to extract data from JSON and display it on client side in javascript :)

Comment: I knew there was a better way - should have thought to use the while loop - thank you for that.  As for the alternate way - I like what you're saying - however - I'm not quite understanding what you mean - I'm getting on well with PHP, and have literally just started learning javascript.  Can you expand on your comment please?

Comment: @SteveShead Sorry in my code i have lost statement :)
After while loop, please add:

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($messages);
die();

Now in your javascript you will get json array instead of html code.

Next iterate over this array and create DOM nodes in your html code by inserting messages as children to #chat container.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking more about the sql statement, and with the help of folks posting here, this is how I solved the issue.  Please let me know if there is a more elegant (correct) way of doing this.  I changed the `getMessages` switch statement to:

```
case "getMessages":

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT m.*, u.role FROM messages m INNER JOIN users u ON m.user = u.username');
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $chat = '';
            foreach($results as $message) {
                if ($message->role == 'Admin') {
                    $chat .= '<div class="single-message border">
                        <strong class="text-uppercase">' . $message->user . ': </strong>[admin]
                        <p> ' . $message->message . '</p>
                        <span class="float-right">' . date('h:i a', strtotime($message->date)) . '</span>
                      </div>';
                } else {
                    $chat .= '<div class="single-message border">
                        <strong class="text-uppercase">' . $message->user . ': </strong>
                        <p> ' . $message->message . '</p>
                        <span class="float-right">' . date('h:i a', strtotime($message->date)) . '</span>
                      </div>';
                }
            }
            echo $chat;
        break;
```

Let me know if there's an easier way. Note I opted to append the username with [admin] instead of changing the text color - seemed a little more user friendly.